# Jquery not loadede: Expected declaration but found '*' Skipped to next declartion [Firefox on Mac]

Tags: jquery, macos, firefox

I have a pretty simple page with two vimeo players on top of each other and on top of this a layer with a selection for one of the two videos.
When clicked it hides layer 1 and shows video 1 or 2.
Jquery is used for this

Problem:
jquery-1.8.2.js is not loaded in firefox 18.0 on Mac.

In developertools I have the following warning:

```
Expected declaration but found '*' Skipped to next declartion
```

What does this mean and how can I solve it?

Comment: it is an css error. there should be a line number where it accourse (i think) it is probably a IE hack for styling

Answer (score -1):

Its a css - browser support error .check if the css attribute is supported by your browser.